# Implementation of nested if else in pyspark map

Tags: python, apache-spark, lambda, pyspark, maps

I have to use lookup function to extract the values from a dataframe using condition from 3 other dataframes. I have implemented nested if else in pyspark map but i am getting syntax errors in if statements. I have no idea what is wrong.

```
aroDF=tempDF.rdd.map(lambda r: if lookupDF.lookup(r["CoreExtractId"] ):

if policyGrpCheckDF.lookup(r["GROUPNUMBER"]):


if PGOffShoreAllowedDF.lookup(r["GROUPNUMBER"]):


IsRestricted=1)
```

I want the tempDF to first check the condition in lookupDF dataframe, the move to policyGrpCheckDF dataframe then move to PGOffShoreAllowedDF dataframe and of all the condition satisfies, the statment will run. CoreExtractId and GROUPNUMBER are column names. Any help would be appreciated.

error is:

```
 aroDF=tempDF.rdd.map(lambda r:  if lookupDF.lookup(r["CoreExtractId"] ):

                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: *i am getting syntax errors* - what are the syntax errors? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. You can't access another DataFrame (or rdd) within a `map` or a `udf`. You need to use a join.

Comment: `if lookupDF.lookup(r["CoreExtractId"]` then what ?? it's just `condition` where is the `action` part ?

Comment: It is checking if some coreextractid from tempDF dataframe is there in lookupDF dataframe or not...if it is there then the condition will be satisfied.

Comment: question is not clear. Hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @vikrantrana I want to achieve basically join of two pyspark dataframes using lookup() function and not using join at all as data is huge. Please suggest me any solution.